# Sitefinity MVC widgets not registering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

Hopefully someone can help me with this, because Sitefinity support appears to be stumped and the community on the G+ page seems stumped also.

I have a dead simple MVC widget:

Controller [~/Mvc/Controllers/TestWidgetController.cs]:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc;

namespace SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Controllers
{
    [ControllerToolboxItem(Name="TestWidget", Title="Test widget", SectionName="Test section")]
    public class TestWidgetController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Model [~/Mvc/Models/TestWidgetModel.cs]:

```
namespace SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models
{
    public class TestWidgetModel
    {
    }
}
```

View [~/Mvc/Views/TestWidget/Index.cshtml]:

```
<p>Test</p>
```

If I take the controller, the model and the view and drop them into a new Sitefinity project, and then build that project, the widget gets registered automatically without any problems and I can use it right away.

However, I have one specific Sitefinity project that I want to drop this widget into, and that project when built does not register the widget automatically.  If I try to register the widget manually I get NullReference exceptions.  It's like the project doesn't actually see those files somehow.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?  I think the simplicity of the widget and the fact that it works in a new Sitefinity project indicates that it's definitely something wrong with the way this particular project has been configured, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

For what it's worth here's the Solution Explorer for the problematic project:

[image: Screenshot of the Solution Explorer]

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell that the controller the page which is returned. Based on the file directory, it is `Index.cshtml` Therefore:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc;

namespace SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Controllers
{
    [ControllerToolboxItem(Name="TestWidget", Title="Test widget", SectionName="Test section")]
    public class TestWidgetController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, when my project use Ninject, I have to tell the controller the view name it needs as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to have MVC widget in a separate assembly that automatically registers itself to the toolbox.

Check [this doc](https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather/wiki/Create-a-%E2%80%9CHello-World%E2%80%9D-MVC-widget-in-a-separate-assembly) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to rename the controller and it toolbox name? Sometime Sitefinity works funny

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are having an issue regarding the widget registration in the controller store. Since most probably this issue is caused by problems related to this specific project it is highly advisable that you go and open a support ticket to the Sitefinity support system.  By doing so your project can be inspected in more details and the most appropriate actions will be recommended.

Apart from that would you please point out the version of your SItefinity project? It will definitely help in the problem investigation.

Also there is an error log file which can be found at ~\App_Data\Sitefinity\Logs. Check and see what is logged there. This can give a clue about what is causing the issue and where to look at for possible solutions.

Regards,

Desislav

Comment: Sending the project is tricky as it's quite large and does contain some sensitive information. I've checked the logs but nothing unexpected was shown there.  Do you have any ideas about what might be wrong in the project that I could look for?  By the way, my version is the most recent release: 7.0.5100.0